# Command-line options in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopt-long

I would like to create a C program that accepts an argument of the form

-aK

where K is some integer from 0-9.

How would I parse/specify this option?

Comment: Use `getopt` ? Or `bsd-getopt_long` ?

Comment: do you know gnu getopt() ?

Comment: After using `getopt`, Try to accept more than 18% ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check out [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) and/or [getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html).

Answer (score 0):

a simple requirement like this can be solved with getopt.

Also you can do this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    char ch, a;
    int d;
    if(argc == 1) return;
    if(argc == 2){
       if(strlen(argv[1]) > 2){
       sscanf(argv[1],"%c%c%d",&ch,&a,&d);
       if(ch == '-' && a == 'a'){
          printf("%d is your number",d);
      }
    }
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @VladLazarenko at least Aniket gave an answer, as opposed to you, who just edits and votes

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, But It did not any bound-checking or parse-checking. This program is potentially crash-able.

Comment: @VladLazarenko explain why its terrible?

Comment: @MasoudM. obviously it was a proof of concept, not production quality. I would certainly use getopt and do all kinds of bounds checking

Comment: @Aniket Well you just gave yourself a hint why it's a terrible example `bound checking`